# List not sorting correctly, with sorted()

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am working on an exercise which in which a function takes a dictionary movies and returns a list with the movies sorted, with the most recent release date being first, and any movies with the year "a long time ago", being last in the list.

When I try sorting a list, I refer to as dates, it does not sort by year, as I intended.

```
def movies_by_release_date(movies):
    long_ago = []
    dates = []
    movies_list = []
    
    for key, value in movies.items():
        year = []
        year.append(value.split(','))
        if year[0][0] == 'a long time ago':
            long_ago.append(key)
        else:
            year[0][0] = int(year[0][0])
            dates.append([key, year[0][0]])
    sorted(dates, key = lambda x:x[1], reverse = True) #This line is intended to sort the list
    
    for i in range(len(dates)):
        movies_list.append(i[0])
    for i in long_ago:
        movies_list.append(i)
    
    return movies_list

print(movies_by_release_date({"Dude, Where’s My Death Star": "a long time ago, in a galaxy far far away",
"Star Wars: The Force Awakens": "2015, in Los Angeles",
"Star Wars": "1977, in Los Angeles",
"Sleepless in Aldera": "a long time ago, in Alderaan City",
"Jurassic World": "2015, in New York"}))
```

The sorted list, `dates` instead outputs the following:

> [['Star Wars: The Force Awakens', 2015], ['Star Wars', 1977], ['Jurassic World', 2015]]

I intended for it to sort according to the year, so Jurassic World should be before Star Wars.

I'm not sure why this is occurring. How could I sort the list as intended?

Answer (score 1):

Either use `.sort(...)` list method, which operates in-place, or assign the result: `sorted(...)`  can accept any iterable and returns sorted result, not modifying the argument.

So you can do either

```
def movies_by_release_date(movies):
    dates = ...
    dates = sorted(dates, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
    ...
```

or

```
def movies_by_release_date(movies):
    dates = ...
    dates.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    ...
```

However, your solution is a bit messy as currently written. Here's what you can do:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def movies_by_release_date(movies):
    long_ago = []
    dates = []

    for film_name, description in movies.items():
        # Do not build nested lists if they are not needed
        year, *_ = description.split(",")
        if year == "a long time ago":
            long_ago.append(film_name)
        else:
            dates.append([film_name, int(year)])

    dates.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return [pair[0] for pair in dates] + long_ago  # Just add the lists together


print(
    movies_by_release_date(
        {
            "Dude, Where’s My Death Star": "a long time ago, in a galaxy far far away",
            "Star Wars: The Force Awakens": "2015, in Los Angeles",
            "Star Wars": "1977, in Los Angeles",
            "Sleepless in Aldera": "a long time ago, in Alderaan City",
            "Jurassic World": "2015, in New York",
        }
    )
)
```